# Socket EACCESS permission denied with Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, remote-access, permission-denied, socketexception

I am trying to connect my android emulator to my host computer with socket connection.

I have a simple Java server running and lessening in the host on port 6789.
I have the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // Declares streamText to refer to text area to show all messages
    TextView streamText = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.streamText));
    streamText.setText("");

    streamText.append("Attempting connection at " + serverIP + " : 6789 \n");
    try {
        connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 6789); // WHAT IP to connect to host, not virtual device host
        streamText.append("Connected to: " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
    }catch(IOException Exception){
        streamText.append(Exception.toString());
        Exception.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

And i am getting this error on logcat:

```
02-05 11:46:52.257    2663-2663/net.ruiruivo.myfirstapp.chatclientv1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: net.ruiruivo.myfirstapp.chatclientv1, PID: 2663
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{net.ruiruivo.myfirstapp.chatclientv1/net.ruiruivo.myfirstapp.chatclientv1.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2071)
        at net.ruiruivo.myfirstapp.chatclientv1.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:33)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
```

And inside my textView window the Exception Says:

java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

I have search this and other sites, the answered that appeared the closest to this was `<permission  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></permission>` in my manifest but did not solved the problem.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Try with,
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
instead of,
<permission  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></permission>

Comment: I saw that and tried with no results, will try again. Thank you

Comment: Yes but the difference to what you wrote is: <uses-permission vs <permission

Comment: I can see the message error in the TextView with my code, but if i switch to the other permission the app doesnt even start and gives error imediatly, i feel something is missing in my code thats all.

Comment: The error message appears in the TextView with: <permission  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></permission>

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is somewhere else.

1.) post your XML file because it seems that you run into a NPE because streamText is null

2.) You can not do network code in the main thread - this will cause a

```
 android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

You have to implement a separate task for that, e.g.:

```
private class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Object>{...}
```

Update:

Here you go:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //your code
    new NetworkTask().execute();
}

private class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Object>{

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Void... v) {

        try {
            //do your network stuff here
            return "";
        } 
        catch (HttpException e) {
            return e;
        }
    }

    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {

        if(result instanceof String){
                //everything was fine
        }
        else{
            if(((HttpException)result).getMessage()!=null){
                //exception occured
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: YESSS i had that problem later ... :) let me repost the later code with another error.

Comment: Well... ill create the thread and test and then post the code if necessary, its a lot of code. Thank you.

Comment: So... my button calls for a Method Run, where can i implement the new thread code please?